# Как убрать чек бокс знаю только тайтл

Tags: javascript

Как убрать чек бокс зная только тайтл при нажатии `onclick='deleTe'`, при условии, что чек бокс уже стоит

```js
function deleTe(q) {
  var myDiv = q.getAttribute('data-value'); // переменная тайтла блока div
}
```

```html
<i data-value='Comp_tion_of_const_iont' onclick='deleTe(this)'>×</i>

<div class="dropdown-checkbox checkbox" id="metro_all">
  <input name="subway" id="metro-4" type="checkbox" value="4" title="Василеостровская" class="panel-checkbox" onclick="metro_click('Василеостровская')">
  <label>Василеостровская</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы не прошли курс по CSS-селекторам?

Comment: Частично срабатывает. Когда переменная myDiv состоит из двух слов с пробелом не срабатывает, это можно скорректировать?

Comment: Так вы вопрос изменить чтобы было правильно указан title в data-attribute

Comment: Обновил ответ с пробелом в title

Comment: Если вы про data-value= там всё ок, он совпадает с тайтлом. И тайтл из одного слова срабатывает.

Comment: Всё  работает! Спасибо. Вижу что вы добавили кавычки, то есть перевели в строку? Так?

Comment: Не перевел в строку, а сделал сравнение атрибута со строкой, которая может содержать пробелы, иначе кавычки можно не указывать.

Comment: То есть без кавычек он сравнивает только слово без кавычек, а с кавычками полностью строку, правильно я понял?

Comment: Без кавычек сравнивает строку до пробела.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!!!!

Comment: Если вы удовлетворены ответами на вопросы, то нужно отмечать их принятыми.

Comment: Без проблем , а где это сделать?

Comment: Вроде понял. Надеюсь верно и спасибо!

Comment: "Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?"

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function deleTe(q) {
  var myDiv = q.getAttribute('data-value'); // переменная тайтла блока div
  console.log(myDiv)
  document.querySelector(`input[title="${myDiv}"]`).checked = false;
}
```

```html
<i data-value='Василеостровская станция' onclick='deleTe(this)'>×</i>

<div class="dropdown-checkbox checkbox" id="metro_all">
  <input name="subway" id="metro-4" type="checkbox" value="4" title="Василеостровская станция" class="panel-checkbox" onclick="metro_click('Василеостровская')">
  <label>Василеостровская</label>
</div>
```